# Add new field to multiple table at once?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add same field to multiple tables. Can I do this with single query in MySql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with a single query, as it requires the `ALTER TABLE` syntax which only supports one table per query (although you could add/modify multiple columns in the same table).

You have to do one `ALTER TABLE` query per table to be modified.

Comment: Yeah, just do 2 SQL statements with ; between them.